Reading the output from arduino slower than it produces the output: what is the buffer size?
I have two different boards with Atmega16U2 (Uno) and ch341 (Nano). They are not genuine actually, but it doesn't matter here I think.
I was asked to look at some code which didn't work as expected. So I started to investigate. Eventually I've come up to the following experiment:
Setup
Arduino code:
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin( 38400 );
}

unsigned n = 0;

void loop()
{
    Serial.println("abracadabra 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
    Serial.println(n);
    n++;
}

So it's just printing the string and the counter value line by line in a loop.
I want to read that output but much slower than it is produced. So, yes, I must go into a data loss. I am using the pySerial lib to read my device, so I have the following reader code:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import serial
import time

s = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', baudrate=38400, timeout=0.1)
# s = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate=38400, timeout=0.1)

def read_arduino() :
    l = str(s.readline().strip())
    print(l)

    if "abracadabra" in l:
        current = int(s.readline().strip().decode("ascii"))
        print(current)
    else :
        print("Error: no key found")
#         exit(1)

time.sleep(10) # wait for the buffer to fill

while True :
    time.sleep(0.01)
    read_arduino()


Also I am using two linux machines running different kernels.
Results
Atmega16U2
...
b'abracadabra 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
64
b'abracadabra 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
65
b'abracaa000000000000000000000'
Error: no key found
b'588'
Error: no key found
b'abraca'
Error: no key found
b'abracadabra 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
587
b'abracadabra 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
588
b'abracadabrracadabra 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
Error: no key found
...

So the data corrupted at n = 65 which means about 4000 bytes has been read correctly (the string is 55 bytes long + the length of the line with the counter value is ~4 bytes long)
ch341
On the machine with an older kernel the data is currupted at n ~ 1300 which means the size of the buffer about 80kB. On the machine with a newer kernel (the one which the results for Atmega16U2 are obtained) it is not corrupted at least until n = 5000 (which results in a much more buffer size).
Question
How do I know the actual buffer size used ? I asked this question on the arduino forum here but didn't get the answer (though I've got some advices). Could you please point me a direction ?
Thank you in advance !
